Adding comment to the nested comment tree gives '[object Object]' error
In a React project, I'm building Nested Comments App. A nested tree is built as and when the new comment is added. New comments are added without any issue until 5th or 6th comment is added. It gives [object Object] error. Please go throught the code shown below.
const [showInput, setShowInput] = useState(false);
  const [showEdDelTab, setShowEdDelTab] = useState(false);
  const [showText, setShowText] = useState("");

  const { addComment } = useComment();

  const handleComment = () => {
    let newComments = {
      id: Date.now(),
      text: showText,
      replies: [],
    };
    const updatedTree = addComment(comments, comments.id, newComments);
    setShowText(updatedTree);
    setShowInput(false);
  };

return (
...
       <div>
          <button onClick={() => setShowInput(true)}>Reply</button>
          {showInput && (
            <>
              <input
                autoFocus
                type="text"
                value={showText}
                onChange={(e) => setShowText(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button disabled={!showText} onClick={() => handleComment()}>
                Comment
              </button>
              <span
                style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                onClick={() => setShowInput(false)}
              >
                X
              </span>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
...
)

The comments json data is being populated from parent component, see below
export default function App() {
  const [comments, setComments] = useState(commentData);

  const handleAddComments = (commentId, newComment) => {
    console.log(commentId, newComment, "comments");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Comments
        key={comments.id}
        comments={comments}
        handleAddComments={handleAddComments}
      />
    </>
  );

And here is the json data being used across the components
export const commentData = {
  id: "1",
  text: "Hello world! How are you?",
  replies: [
    {
      id: "2",
      text: "Hey, I am fine, wau?",
      replies: [
        {
          id: "3",
          text: "Hello, I am food, How are you?",
          replies: [
            {
              id: "4",
              text: "Life sucks man!",
              replies: [
                {
                  id: "5",
                  text: "Haha, I can relate :)",
                  replies: [],
                },
              ],
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};



Above is an image which depicts error
This is the given specific code due to which error is aroused. Any appropriate solution or suggestion highly appreciated.
Please go to the codesandbox link -> https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-comment-app-mc-r92w4g

you're missing the top half your component there. in any case it's likely when you save the comment and pull it back through you're pulling though the newComment object not the text string. log out your component props and the issue will become obvious

@danielRICADO if possible can you please update it in the codesandbox

I get sandbox not found, you can add a log and read that yourself bud.

Please do not add external sources to code. Make your question self contained. Give us a [mre] that we can copy and debug in our IDE. For example; what is comments?

@ChukwujiobiCanon Please see, I have now edited the post

Technicaly note: that's not JSON data. That's a normal JS object. Having said that, please don't show a bunch of related, separate code blocks: turn this problem into a [mcve] and then show that so that folks can quickly test it to verify that the problem indeed happens, and can then post fixes to your MRE in their own answers.

Code is incomplete, also the codesandbox link is not working. Please provide the full code or update the codesandbox link.

@MudassarMalik The link is opening, please check once

It says Sandbox not found

@MudassarMalik Actually it had new sandbox configuration where access was private, now its made public. Now you can check. Thanks in advance

Here [object Object] is displayed in showText after adding a comment. In your current implementation, showText is intended to hold the text of the new comment being typed, but it seems you're assigning an object (updatedTree) to showText, which causes it to display [object Object].
Here Are the updated handleComment method code


const handleComment = () => {
  if (!showText) return; // Prevent adding empty comments

  let newComment = {
    id: Date.now(),
    text: showText,
    replies: [],
  };

  // Add the new comment to the existing comments structure
  const updatedTree = addComment(comments, comments.id, newComment);

  // Pass the updated comments tree up to the parent component
  handleAddComments(comments.id, updatedTree);

  // Reset the input field and text state
  setShowText(""); // Reset to empty string after adding comment
  setShowInput(false); // Hide the input field after adding comment
};



